# Switch cases in algorithmic

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx

How can I use switch cases in `algorithmicx`? For example a code like this:

`switch s do`
`--case a`
`----assert(1)`
`--case b`
`----assert(0)`

etc.
Is is possible to define it as a command?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use the following:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}% http://ctan.org/pkg/algorithmicx
\begin{document}
% New definitions
\algnewcommand\algorithmicswitch{\textbf{switch}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmiccase{\textbf{case}}
\algnewcommand\algorithmicassert{\texttt{assert}}
\algnewcommand\Assert[1]{\State \algorithmicassert(#1)}%
% New "environments"
\algdef{SE}[SWITCH]{Switch}{EndSwitch}[1]{\algorithmicswitch\ #1\ \algorithmicdo}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmicswitch}%
\algdef{SE}[CASE]{Case}{EndCase}[1]{\algorithmiccase\ #1}{\algorithmicend\ \algorithmiccase}%
\algtext*{EndSwitch}%
\algtext*{EndCase}%

\begin{algorithmic}[1]
  \Switch{$s$}
    \Case{$a$}
      \Assert{0}
    \EndCase
    \Case{$b$}
      \Assert{1}
    \EndCase
  \EndSwitch
\end{algorithmic}
\end{document}​
```

Both new "environments" `\Switch`...`\EndSwitch` and `\Case`...`\EndCase` are defined to have beginning and ending text. However, using `\algnotext*{<env>}` removes any typesetting of that command, effectively removing the ending command for both `\Switch` and `\Case`. It's still needed, since there may be more than one entry so its not possible to generalise with some number-of-lines-termination.